# in ubuntu10.10 Apache installing xsl

Tags: php, apache

I need a quick support, How to install/enable xsl extension for ubuntu10.10 php5 apache. i tried this command "sudo apt-get install php5-xsl" getting some kinds of errors

```
1) 404  Not Found
2) Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
3)Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-xsl_5.3.3-1ubuntu9.10_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
```

Comment: Did you try the `apt-get update`?

Comment: @madth3 this command also i tried getting this type of similiar errors W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/restricted/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

Comment: Seems like server or system configuration problems. I'd searching for this in askubuntu.com